# Coreplot iOS - Color space between graph bars

Tags: ios, swift, bar-chart, core-plot

I am using CorePlot iOS library to create a bar chart for my application.Though I want alternate colors in the spaces between the bars.
Have been stuck on this for a while .Can you guide me if this is possible and how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `alternatingBandFills` on the axis. This is an array of `CPTFill`, `CPTColor`, `CPTGradient`, `CPTImage`, or `[NSNull null]` objects. The fills are drawn between each major tick location on the axis behind the plot.